# Retrieve Service Bus event hub connection string

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have an existing Service Bus with one queue and event hub deployed using Azure Resource Manager.

Now I am interested to retrieve the primary key and connection string using Azure PowerShell wiithout using the ServiceBus.dll. Is it possible??

As a workaround I have created an ARM template which does not deploy anything but just query the existing resource and retrieve the information I need. The below template retrieves the connection string and primary key of an event hub/queue for a specific service bus namespace

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serviceBusNamespace": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the service bus namespace to create."
            }
        },
        "resourceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the resource to be retreived."
            }
        },
        "resourceType": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "allowedValues": [
                "queues",
                "eventhubs"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of the resource"
            }
        },
        "policy": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "defaultValue": "ManagePolicy",
            "allowedValues": [
                "ManagePolicy",
                "SendPolicy",
                "ListenPolicy"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of the resource"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [ ],
    "outputs": {
        "connectionString": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/',parameters('resourceType'),'/authorizationRules'),parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('resourceName'),parameters('policy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        },
        "primaryKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/',parameters('resourceType'),'/authorizationRules'),parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('resourceName'),parameters('policy')),'2015-08-01').primaryKey]"
        }
    }
}
```

Is it abusing to use ARM template to **query** for a resource and not actually deploy anything?

**EDIT** 
To capture the output of the ARM template within PowerShell use the below code

```
$ep = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "getEventHub" -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Mode Incremental -TemplateFile getEventHub.json -TemplateParameterFile getEventHub.param.json
$RuleConnString = $ep.Outputs.connectionString.value
$RulePrimaryKey = $ep.Outputs.primaryKey.value
```

Note that the property names ***connectionString*** and ***primaryKey*** are same as defined in my template file

**EDIT 2**
If I re-run the ARM template to deploy the event hub second time I get the below error. [image]

I din't find any option other than to use the ARM template to query the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to get the information you are seeking. The Resource Manager provides a common interface to interact with all the services. It is how the Portal access the services, and each of the language SDKs are just wrappers for similar requests to the one you have created.

I usually use the Python or java SDKs, but I have been told that NodeJS is a very easy way to wrap the Web APIs that ARM calls to construct similar calls like the one you made, if you are looking for a none ARM way to do this.

Comment: Do you have a sample for Node.js? Is it possible to consume the output from NodeJS in powershell easily?

Comment: NodeJS would not be to mix with powershell, but instead if you wanted to make an interface or gui for what you are doing. I'll see what I can find.  The Powershell cmdlet's you want specifically start with "*-azurerm". those will mix nicely with arm templates

Comment: Currently the team is focusing only on Automation using PowerShell. So for now I don't think NodeJS will be of help currently. Until then I will stick to ARM.Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I don’t see what’s wrong with what you’re doing. In my view Resource Manager templates in their nature are incremental. So you could author a template to create your existing service bus with the same resources. If the properties are the same then it will leave the existing resources intact and return you the connection string and primary key of the relevant resource.

I have a need to automate the creation of a service bus and queue and separate send/listen shared access policies. You can retrieve the connection string on the service bus itself using PowerShell natively without using the .Net ServiceBus.dll assembly by using Get-AzureSBAuthorizationRule but due to a still current bug this doesn’t work at the queue level.

I tried using the ServiceBus.dll to create the shared access policies but sometimes it would randomly fail but subsequently work if you ran it a second time immediately afterwards. I also tried Resource Manager templates but previously you had to pass in the keys you’d generated yourself. Now I see Microsoft generate those for you but you’re still left trying to get the key in an automated fashion so I like your solution.

One question though, can you capture the Resource Manager template outputs and pass them back to a PowerShell script, do you know?

Cheers

Rob

```
{   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#", "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",   "parameters": {
    "servicebusNamespace": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The service bus namespace"
      }
    },
    "notificationssmsqueue": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Notifications SMS queue"
      }
    }   },   "variables": {
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",   },   "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('servicebusNamespace')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "messagingSku": 2
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "[parameters('notificationssmsqueue')]",
          "type": "Queues",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('servicebusNamespace'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "path": "[parameters('notificationssmsqueue')]"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.listen')]",
              "type": "AuthorizationRules",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('notificationssmsqueue')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "keyName": "[concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.listen')]",
                "claimType": "SharedAccessKey",
                "claimValue": "None",
                "rights": [ "Listen" ],
                "revision": -1
              }
            },
            {
              "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.send')]",
              "type": "AuthorizationRules",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('notificationssmsqueue')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "keyName": "[concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.send')]",
                "claimType": "SharedAccessKey",
                "claimValue": "None",
                "rights": [ "Send" ],
                "revision": -1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }   ],   "outputs": {
    "connectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules'),parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'RootManageSharedAccessKey'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
    },
    "smsSendPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/Queues/AuthorizationRules'),parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.send')),'2015-08-01').PrimaryKey]"
    },
    "smsListenPrimaryKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(resourceId(concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/Queues/AuthorizationRules'),parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),concat(parameters('notificationssmsqueue'),'.listen')),'2015-08-01').PrimaryKey]"
    }   } }
```

But I call my templates like this:

New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile "$scripts_folder$SB_create_script" -TemplateParameterObject `
 @{ servicebusNamespace = $servicebusNamespace; 
 notificationssmsqueue = $NotificationSMSqueue }

Comment: If i re-run the ARM template to redeploy the Service Bus and shared access policies the powershell fails with an error. So I had no choice but use the template posted. The Get-AzureSBAuthorizationRule does not work for RM deployed resources I guess. As to your question of being able to capture the ARM outputs in PS the short answer is ***yes***

Comment: Why don't you modify your original template and add your outputs and re-run it? I have a template that creates a service bus and shared access policies and have added your outputs and I can re-run it fine and it returns the keys without failing. Happy to share it if you like? How do you capture the ARM template outputs for use in PowerShell, that's the bit I'm missing.

Comment: Updated the question with a code which shows how to read the output of the ARM template.

Comment: Thanks Sandesh. Let me know if you want me to posy my template.

Comment: I did try to re-run the same ARM template twice and it failed with an error. Can you post your template so that I can see and understand as to why it runs in your case?

Comment: Have posted my template and how I call it. It creates a service bus and a queue with two shared access policies but you should be able to adapt it.

Comment: What happens if you call the same template file with same parameters second time?

Comment: If nothing has changed on the Service Bus or queue it would just return the output values. If the queue had been deleted, as an example, it would re-create it and return the output values. As you would expect from a Resource Manager template.

Comment: I found a different behaviour from my end. If I re-run the same template I get the error which is attached in my question. Which version of Azure PowerShell are you using? Also my template creates queue and event hub both simultaneously and I would not prefer to re-run the entire template just for outputs

Comment: I'm using the latest 1.3.0 but I don't think it's a version problem you're having. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Yeah I will figure something out